# Why does my addEvent function need to be self-invoking?

Tags: javascript, function, alias, self-invoking-function

I am teaching myself to code using javascript and one of the things that really got me excited was the ability to create a custom (shorter) version of addEventListener.

I have the following code:

```
var onEvent = function() {
 return function(obj, event, fn) {
   obj.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
 }; 
}();

onEvent(input,"keypress", pressedEnter);
```

(for my own personal usage i prefer using "When" rather than "onEvent".

After researching I think I understand that adding the () at the end of the function runs it. But why is this necessary? Won't the function run as soon as it's added to an object that will be clicked?

Similarly, I've created a shorter getElementById:

```
function grab(id) { 
 return document.getElementById(id); 
}
```

Why does this not need to run itself before being used? Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the ending parentheses?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no point to the immediately-invoked function in the first bit of code.

Comment: If i remove the parenthesis it won't work.

Comment: Remove the entire surrounding anonymous function. Make it look like your `grab()` function. How did it get the way it is in the first place?

Comment: I found it here http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-no-no/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var onEvent = function(obj, event, fn) {
  obj.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
};
```

Should do exactly the same.

Comment: Ok my fault it wasn't working when i tried but that was related to another error, so you are actually right it works just as well, thank you! However is there a reason the code is shown with the parentheses by Dustin Diaz here: http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-no-no/

Comment: Yes there is, you can see in his code that he has an if-Statement where he checks if addEventListener exists. So basically he is checking if the browser supports addEventListener and returns another function in case it doesn't.

Comment: Yes I noticed that, i stripped out the if statement for attachevent for my own clarity and because the ie versions it targets are almost irrelevant to me. but why does the if statement require the ending parenthesis? It's basically doing this: var addEvent = function() { }();

Comment: Basically the outer function spits out ANOTHER function (depending on what event adding functionality the browser supports). For it in order to spit out the function, you first need to call it. The event adding function suitable for the browser gets then assigned to onEvent. If you didn't add the parentheses, you would have a function that returns another function. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It might dawn on me over time, right now my brain is overloaded with new info (just went through making a todo app) so I'm a bit confused, to me all I see is ` var addEvent = function() { }() ` and seeing as all the functions within that variable have all their appropriate parentheses and curly braces, the ending seems superfluous.

Comment: The important part is the `return function(){}` INSIDE of the curly braces ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your outer annonymous (without a name) function is used to define and return an inner function.

That makes sense if you need to do this in an local environment. i.e. if you want to define private variables which are only visible in the outer and inner function but not outside of the outer function. Or, your may want to `use "strict"` inside the outer function.

It make also sense if the creation of the inner function depends on the context. Then, perhaps you want to return different functions depending on contextual information.